# Event store in Azure

Tags: azure

As per my understanding,an event store is simply a data store for all the events. This can be anything from a relational database to NoSQL, but should be optimized for storing and querying large amounts of non-relational data.So we can use following services to store events in Azure:

1. Azure Table storage
2. Azure SQL Server
3. Azure Cosmos DB
4. Azure Event Hub

Which of the above service is intended for Event Sourcing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event Hubs are more-or-less a "Pub-Sub" mechanism. You can send events to it and it will broadcast those events to whoever is listening.

Azure Table storage, SQL server and CosmosDB stores data... They each store it in a very different ways, but in the end, their job is to store the data. Each one of these technologies have "change-feed" notifications (notify a listener when data changes in a document or row), but it's not nearly as reliable as a technology that is built to produce events in real-time.

Event Hubs can store data, but for a very short amount of time... For example, you can set the TTL on EH data to 3 days. That means a message will live in there for 3 days allowing subscribers to grab that message.

You can wire Event Hubs up to other services, for example: Stream Analytics... that can analyze the data and do something with it... for example: send it to a storage mechanism such as a Data Lake.

So of all the technologies you asked about, you would probably want an Event Hub to source events.

I use them in my architectures... I have a hub that processes millions of events a day from thousands of clients with no issues in latency or downtime. They are amazing in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer..One question though..If Event Hubs can store data, but for a very short amount of time, then the purpose of Event Sourcing pattern can be defeated. How can I replay event or query events later if the events are not persisted in the store?

Comment: @ronit -- It's just a pub-sub. I would assume you would have a listener that would pull the events in real-time to another storage medium that is long term (maybe a datalake or warehouse), then analyze from there. The point of an Event Hub is to get data to subscribers quickly, not to store data long term.

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question, the question is where to store those events

Answer (score 9):

For storing the underlying event stream both **CosmosDb** and **Azure Table storage** are good solutions - I use the latter extensively but there are good examples using CosmosDb from JET.

**Event Hubs** is not ideal as a backing store because in event sourcing you want to store events forever.  You can, of course, forward event hub events to a persistent storage but will end up using that storage as your source of truth for the event sourcing.

Lots of implementations of event sourcing do exist on **SQL Server** but I prefer not to have a locked-in event schema as it adds a lot of work.

For CosmsoDb take a look at:
[JAT/Equinox on GitHub](https://github.com/jet/equinox)

For Azure table storage I have this example: [EventsSourcing-on-Azure-Functions on GitHub](https://github.com/MerrionComputing/EventsSourcing-on-Azure-Functions)

Comment: I like eventhub for a temporary event store, where i think of events in eventhub as operations, that are once in a while snapshotted (for example blob storage, sql, whatever). Ie state = last snapshot + events (this is the write model part)

Answer (score 3):

I think [Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2018/february/azure-event-driven-architecture-in-the-cloud-with-azure-event-grid) would be the service most geared toward an [event-driven architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/architecture-styles/event-driven).

But there are a lot more possible combinations. I have found that using Cosmos DB with its [Change Feed to trigger Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-functions) is a great way to build events into your database and respond to any data change with specific actions.